# I cant use VirtualBox in my Ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and I want to use VirtualBox 6.1. I installed that successfully,and I added extension pack successfully. But when I try to use my usb in my virtual machine I get a warning message which is "no devices available". I know it is not about ubuntu exactly, but when I tried in Windows I was worked. Can you help me how can I solve this problem.

Comment: What sort of device are you trying to use? A USB memory stick? A USB dongle? A USB scanner? … 

Comment: My device is an usb wifi adaptor, and Jay-Pi's comment helped me to solve it. thanks all of you

Answer (score 0):

Please add your user name to the vboxusers group with this command:

```sh
sudo adduser $USER vboxusers
```

Then restart.

[Link to related ubuntu help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/USB)